# how to enable hyperZ on radeon hd 5000 series?

Tags: kernel, radeon, amd-graphics

I have surfed around the web to enabling hyperZ by adding this parameter `R600_DEBUG=hyperz`, but where I must put it? Is it at `/etc/default/grub` ?

My Card : Ati Mobility Radeon HD5650

Answer (score 1):

After asking on phoronix forums, just put

```
R600_HYPERZ=1
```

in `/home/$USER/.profile`

Comment: Where is the answer to the other part of the question? Are you satisfied with the answer? If yes, remove the extra parts from question or add details addressing those and accept the answer